# Organization method on sharing research within a company

Tags: methodology

Currently we are trying to organize a methodology how different teams can share theirs projects with other team. These projects can be papers, code, pptx, views on everything.

Is there a known scheme ; data lake or everything than can be useful to our company for this?

We recently found that two teams where creating the same projects without knowing it.

I am open to papers or exemples that have already worked in real life.

Answer (score 1):

I enjoy using Gitlab. Even though its main feature is support for the code versioning tool `git`, it has much more functionality, including a great web interface where everyone can organize and share their work. I think Github is similar.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion however GitLab is just like a Github. It is not that user friendly when you have pptx or other non coding projects